# Convert List of Tuples to Dictionary 2 different ways

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of tuples.

```
[('0', 'Hadoop'), ('0', 'Big Data'), ('0', 'HBas'), ('0', 'Java'), ('0', 'Spark'), ('0', 'Storm'), ('0', 'Cassandra'), ('1', 'NoSQL'), ('1', 'MongoDB'), ('1', 'Cassandra'), ('1', 'HBase'), ('1', 'Postgres'), ('2', 'Python'), ('2', 'skikit-learn'), ('2', 'scipy'), ('2', 'numpy'), ('2', 'statsmodels'), ('2', 'pandas'), ('3', 'R'), ('3', 'Python'), ('3', 'statistics'), ('3', 'regression'), ('3', 'probability'), ('4', 'machine learning'), ('4', 'regression'), ('4', 'decision trees'), ('4', 'libsvm'), ('5', 'Python'), ('5', 'R'), ('5', 'Java'), ('5', 'C++'), ('5', 'Haskell'), ('5', 'programming languages'), ('6', 'statistics'), ('6', 'probability'), ('6', 'mathematics'), ('6', 'theory'), ('7', 'machine learning'), ('7', 'scikit-learn'), ('7', 'Mahout'), ('7', 'neural networks'), ('8', 'neural networks'), ('8', 'deep learning'), ('8', 'Big Data'), ('8', 'artificial intelligence'), ('9', 'Hadoop'), ('9', 'Java'), ('9', 'MapReduce'), ('9', 'Big Data')]
```

The values on the left are "employee id numbers" while the values on the right are "interests". I have to turn these into dictionaries in two different ways: I have to make the employee id number the key and the interests the value, then I have to make the interests the key and the employee id number the value. Basically, as a quick example, I need one of the elements of my end result to look like this:

```
{'0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'],
 '1' ... etc]}
```

Then the next would look like this:

```
{'Hadoop': [0,9]...}
```

I tried default dict but couldn't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're on the right track.  To do the first: 1) create an empty dict 2) loop over each entry, and for each entry a) if that employee doesn't yet exist in the dict, add a new entry in the dict that has the id as the key and an empty list for the value.  Then b) add the interest to the list for that employee id. - this is a very standard idiom done over and over in programming.

Comment: If you're in a class, I bet you won't want to use 'defaultdict'.  It hides the interesting details I outlined that I bet your instructor is going to want to see.  maybe I'm wrong, but defaultdict is a bit of a cop out. - it won't always be as simple as what defaultdict does.  you'll need to understand what's going on at a bit lower level at some point.  If this were a class I was teaching, I'd want to see the logic of adding an entry the first time for each employee, and then adding to the array in the value for each interest for that employee.  Just my $.02.

Comment: I'm assuming a for loop is the way to go here then?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('0', 'Hadoop'),
('0', 'Big Data'),
('0', 'HBas'),
('0', 'Java'),.....]

result = defaultdict(list)
for idVal, interest in lst:
    result[idVal].append(interest)
print(result)

result = defaultdict(list)
for idVal, interest in lst:
    result[interest].append(idVal)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['NoSQL', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'HBase', 'Postgres'], '0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'], '3': ['R', 'Python', 'statistics', 'regression', 'probability'], '2': ['Python', 'skikit-learn', 'scipy', 'numpy', 'statsmodels', 'pandas'], '5': ['Python', 'R', 'Java', 'C++', 'Haskell', 'programming languages'], '4': ['machine learning', 'regression', 'decision trees', 'libsvm'], '7': ['machine learning', 'scikit-learn', 'Mahout', 'neural networks'], '6': ['statistics', 'probability', 'mathematics', 'theory'], '9': ['Hadoop', 'Java', 'MapReduce', 'Big Data'], '8': ['neural networks', 'deep learning', 'Big Data', 'artificial intelligence']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Java': ['0', '5', '9'], 'neural networks': ['7', '8'], 'NoSQL': ['1'], 'Hadoop': ['0', '9'], 'Mahout': ['7'], 'Storm': ['0'], 'regression': ['3', '4'], 'statistics': ['3', '6'], 'probability': ['3', '6'], 'programming languages': ['5'], 'Python': ['2', '3', '5'], 'deep learning': ['8'], 'Haskell': ['5'], 'mathematics': ['6'], 'HBas': ['0'], 'numpy': ['2'], 'pandas': ['2'], 'artificial intelligence': ['8'], 'theory': ['6'], 'libsvm': ['4'], 'C++': ['5'], 'R': ['3', '5'], 'HBase': ['1'], 'Spark': ['0'], 'Postgres': ['1'], 'decision trees': ['4'], 'Big Data': ['0', '8', '9'], 'MongoDB': ['1'], 'scikit-learn': ['7'], 'MapReduce': ['9'], 'machine learning': ['4', '7'], 'scipy': ['2'], 'skikit-learn': ['2'], 'statsmodels': ['2'], 'Cassandra': ['0', '1']})
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the beginning part? The defaultdict(<type list>, portion?

Comment: @jacknovozinsky - `print(dict(result))`

Comment: Why iterate the list twice?

Comment: @RoadRunner Main intent is to just show the use of `collections.defaultdict` for OP

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` is indeed the right way to go about this. Create one for each dictionary you want, then loop over the list and add each pair to both dictionaries.

```
import collections

ids = collections.defaultdict(list)
interests = collections.defaultdict(list)

for ident,interest in data:
    ids[ident].append(interest)
    interests[interest].append(ident)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `pandas`?

```
data = [('0', 'Hadoop'),
('0', 'Big Data'),
('0', 'HBas'),...]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_1 = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
df_2 = df.groupby(1)[0].apply(list)

print( df_1.to_dict() )
print( df_2.to_dict() )
```

Outcome:

```
{'0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', '...
{'Big Data': ['0', '8', '9'], 'C++' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Most pythonic and shortest code and **without using imports** that I can think of:

```
alist = [('0', 'Hadoop'),
('0', 'Big Data'),
('0', 'HBas'),
('0', 'Java'),
('0', 'Spark'),
('0', 'Storm'),...]

adict = {}
bdict = {}
for key, value in alist:
    adict[key] = adict.get(key, []) + [value]
    bdict[value] = bdict.get(value, []) + [key]
```

Outputs:

```
print(adict)
#{'0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'], '1': ['NoSQL', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'HBase', 'Postgres'],...}

print(bdict)
#{'Hadoop': ['0', '9'], 'Big Data': ['0', '8', '9'], 'HBas': ['0'], 'Java': ['0', '5', '9'], 'Spark': ['0'], 'Storm': ['0'],...}
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` is the faster option, but you could also group with `setdefault()` with one pass through the list:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
for fst, snd in l:
    d1.setdefault(fst, []).append(snd)
    d2.setdefault(snd, []).append(fst)

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Which Outputs:

```
{'0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'],
 '1': ['NoSQL', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'HBase', 'Postgres'],
 '2': ['Python', 'skikit-learn', 'scipy', 'numpy', 'statsmodels', 'pandas'],
 '3': ['R', 'Python', 'statistics', 'regression', 'probability'],
 '4': ['machine learning', 'regression', 'decision trees', 'libsvm'],
 '5': ['Python', 'R', 'Java', 'C++', 'Haskell', 'programming languages'],
 '6': ['statistics', 'probability', 'mathematics', 'theory'],
 '7': ['machine learning', 'scikit-learn', 'Mahout', 'neural networks'],
 '8': ['neural networks',
       'deep learning',
       'Big Data',
       'artificial intelligence'],
 '9': ['Hadoop', 'Java', 'MapReduce', 'Big Data']}
{'Big Data': ['0', '8', '9'],
 'C++': ['5'],
 'Cassandra': ['0', '1'],
 'HBas': ['0'],
 'HBase': ['1'],
 'Hadoop': ['0', '9'],
 'Haskell': ['5'],
 'Java': ['0', '5', '9'],
 'Mahout': ['7'],
 'MapReduce': ['9'],
 'MongoDB': ['1'],
 'NoSQL': ['1'],
 'Postgres': ['1'],
 'Python': ['2', '3', '5'],
 'R': ['3', '5'],
 'Spark': ['0'],
 'Storm': ['0'],
 'artificial intelligence': ['8'],
 'decision trees': ['4'],
 'deep learning': ['8'],
 'libsvm': ['4'],
 'machine learning': ['4', '7'],
 'mathematics': ['6'],
 'neural networks': ['7', '8'],
 'numpy': ['2'],
 'pandas': ['2'],
 'probability': ['3', '6'],
 'programming languages': ['5'],
 'regression': ['3', '4'],
 'scikit-learn': ['7'],
 'scipy': ['2'],
 'skikit-learn': ['2'],
 'statistics': ['3', '6'],
 'statsmodels': ['2'],
 'theory': ['6']}
```

Comment: Nice, have a look at my answer too. I used `.get` in place of your `.setdefault`. Thanks, I learnt something about your method. Would you think yours is faster?

Comment: @ycx Nice, that also works well :). I was going to use `defaultdict` but already saw two other answers with it.

Comment: Do you know if `setdefault` and `append` is faster than `get` and `+`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using a `set` and `dict` comprehension.

```
data = [('0', 'Hadoop'),
('0', 'Big Data'),
('0', 'HBas'),
('0', 'Java'),
...]

ids = {id_[0] for id_ in data}
d = {id_: [intrest[1] for intrest in data if intrest[0] == id_] for id_ in ids}
```

This results in:

```
{'9': ['Hadoop', 'Java', 'MapReduce', 'Big Data'], '8': ['neural networks', 'deep learning', 'Big Data', 'artificial intelligence'], '6': ['statistics', 'probability', 'mathematics', 'theory'], '3': ['R', 'Python', 'statistics', 'regression', 'probability'], '2': ['Python', 'skikit-learn', 'scipy', 'numpy', 'statsmodels', 'pandas'], '5':['Python', 'R', 'Java', 'C++', 'Haskell', 'programming languages'],'4': ['machine learning', 'regression', 'decision trees', 'libsvm'], '0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'], '1': ['NoSQL', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'HBase', 'Postgres'], '7': ['machine learning', 'scikit-learn', 'Mahout', 'neural networks']}
```

**Edit**

This is more efficient if using itertools groupby.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

id_intrests = groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))
d = {id_: [_[1] for _ in intrests] for id_, intrests in id_intrests}
```

Comment: also making the guy run before teaching him to walk.  I'm pretty sure his instructor isn't going to want to see this.

Comment: You are right I wasn't exactly taking that into consideration.

Comment: I've never done this where i let duplication get taken care of by the container...or the comprehension.  computing the 'ids'...is that inefficient if you have lots of duplicate keys?

Comment: To be honest I considered taking my answer down until you asked that, I can look into a possibly more efficient way

Comment: @Steve I made an edit. I believe this would be more efficient.

Comment: This is essentially the same as Chris's answer but using itemgetter instead of lambda

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

tups = [('0', 'Hadoop'),
('0', 'Big Data'),
('0', 'HBas'),
...]

{k:list(zip(*v))[1] for k, v in itertools.groupby(tups, key=lambda x:x[0])}

{'0': ('Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'),
...
 '9': ('Hadoop', 'Java', 'MapReduce', 'Big Data')}

{k:list(zip(*v))[0] for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(tups, key=lambda x:x[1]), key=lambda x:x[1])}

{'Big Data': ('0', '8', '9'),
 ...
 'theory': ('6',)}
```